# Why is ${6 \choose 2} - 1=14$?

Tags: notation

> $${6 \choose 2} - 1=14$$

I found this in a quantum computing paper and I cannot understand why the result is $14$. This looks like a vector, and I do not know how to properly treat a problem like this.

Comment: This is unreadable. Link to paper?

Comment: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41534-019-0240-1/MediaObjects/41534_2019_240_MOESM1_ESM.pdf

Comment: if you can check the caption in figure S4

Comment: I guess you mean ${6 \choose 2} - 1$ , right?

Comment: yes, sorry for my post not being clear

Comment: $\binom{6}{2} = \frac{6\cdot 5}{2} = 15$

Comment: @G.Chri: You read that as a binomial 6-choose-2 = 15 - 1 = 14, see https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\binom{n}{r}$ is an alternative (more common amongst people who've studied higher-level math) to the notation $^{n}\mathrm{C}_r$, representing the number of combinations of $r$ objects from $n$, i.e. the number of ways to choose $r$ different numbers from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with order not being important.

The formula is $$\binom nr=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!},,$$ which for $n=6,r=2$ gives $15$.